# finding text between <script></script> tags with RegEx for Coldfusion including linebreaks

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I am trying to extract javascript code from HTML content that I receive via CFHTTP request.

I have this simple regex that catches everyting as long as there is no linebreak in the code between the tags.

```
var result=REMatch("<script[^>]*>(.*?)</script>",html);
```

This will catch:

```
<script>testtesttest</script<
```

but not

```
<script>
testtest

</script>
```

I have tried to use (?m) for multiline, but it doesn't work like that.
I am using the [reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0a38f-7ffb.html) to figure it out but I am just not getting it with regex.

Heads up, normally there would be javascript between the script tags, not simple text so also characters like {}();:-_ etc.

Can anyone help me out?

Cheers

[[UPDATE]]
Thanks guys, I will try the solutions. I favor regex because but I will look into the HTML Parser too.

Comment: Might be better to use a proper HTML parser than RegEx: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2341-ColdFusion-10-Parsing-Dirty-HTML-Into-Valid-XML-Documents.htm | http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2358-Parsing-Traversing-And-Mutating-HTML-With-ColdFusion-And-jSoup.htm. This is worth a read just for the comedy value: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/419 :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`(?m)` multiline mode is for making `^` and `$` match on line breaks (not just start/end of string as is default), but what you're trying to do here is make `.` include newlines - for that you want `(?s)` (dot-all mode).

However, I probably wouldn't do this with regex - **a HTML parser is a more robust solution**. Here's how to do it with [jSoup](http://jsoup.org):

```
var result = jsoup.parse(html).select('script').text();
```

More details on using jSoup in CF are [available here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2358-Parsing-Traversing-And-Mutating-HTML-With-ColdFusion-And-jSoup.htm), or alternatively you can use the [TagSoup](http://home.ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/) parser, which [ships with CF10](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2341-ColdFusion-10-Parsing-Dirty-HTML-Into-Valid-XML-Documents.htm) (so you don't need to worry about jars/etc).

If you really want regex, then you can use this:

```
var result = rematch('<script[^>]*>(?:[^<]+|<(?!/script>))+',html);
```

Unlike using `(?s).*?` this avoids matching empty  blocks (but it will still fail in certain edge cases - if accuracy is required use a HTML parser).

To extract just the text from the first script block, you can strip the script tag with this:

```
result = ListRest( result[1] , '>' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dot matches all mode or replace `.` with `[\s\S]` to get the same effect.

```
<script[^>]*>[\s\S]*?</script> would match everything including newlines.
```

Comment: The only reason to use `[\s\S]` is when `(?s)` isn't available (but it is here).

Comment: @PeterBoughton, your answer mentioned ?s modifier and so I mentioned the other alternative